# "while (c = getchar())" equivalent in c++

Tags: c++, loops, input, char

Is there some kind of idiomatic expression using the c++ iostream library which is similar to the

```
while (c = getchar())
```

idiom in c?

note:  I left the statement at simply "c = getchar()" to allow it to be more generic. In real code, I would compare the result of this to something else such as an EOF or newline.

Comment: `while(std::cin >> c)`.

Comment: @Rapptz: you forgot `std::cin >>std::noskipws`

Comment: @MooingDuck Oops, yeah.

Comment: I hope that's not an idiom in C, since that'd be an infinite loop when it reached the end of the file, and would break out at the first zero byte.  `while ((c = getchar())) != EOF)` maybe?

Comment: @MooingDuck ...or maybe just `getchar();` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char c;
    std::cin >> std::noskipws;
    while(std::cin >> c) {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `noskipws` is sticky and doesn't need to be set each time. Moreover going through the formatting routines (with formatting disabled) wastes time. Use `std::cin.get(c)`.

Answer (score 6):

The closest equivalent to getchar() is [std::istream::get()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/):

```
while ((c = std::cin.get()))
```

Note the double parentheses; these are used to avoid a compiler warning about using `=` instead of `==` in the loop condition.

Comment: wait, I just noticed, THIS CODE IS WRONG! O.o  Totally didn't notice that the loop exit condition is 100% wrong the first like 3 times I read this answer. (protip: `while(std::cin.get(c))`)

Comment: @MooingDuck How is it wrong? I'm using the overload of istream::get() that returns the character that was read or EOF. This is the exact same semantics as getchar(). I even linked to the cplusplus.com's docs of istream::get() where you can see the various overloads. The one I'm using is the one labeled "(1) single character". The OP's code `while (c = getchar())` translates *exactly* to `while (c = std::cin.get())`, with exact same semantics.

Comment: On further review, you're right it does translate exactly, and the bug I saw is _also_ in the OP's code.  My bad.  I'll make a tiny edit to the post so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: No upvote though, because you neither fixed nor mentioned the common errors that are associated with the OP's code.

Comment: @MooingDuck OP's code lacks context though, so it's impossible to know what the intention is.

Comment: Here I found the C++ equivalent for `getchar();` -- the [press enter] idiom ;)

Answer (score 0):

> note: I left the statement at simply "c = getchar()" to allow it to be more generic. In real code, I would compare the result of this to something else such as an EOF or newline.

Um, that's *less* generic. If it's the generic version of anything, it generically expresses a common error. *All* software should handle an EOF condition *anywhere*.

In C++ we use stream buffers, which compare as true-or-false values depending on success. There is no need to use EOF as a fake stream value, although you can choose to do so.

The idiom (sans bug) would be

```
while ( std::cin.get( c ) )
```

If you want to consume up to the next newline and parse one line per iteration, with no requirement to end the file with an empty line, then use

```
std::string s;
while ( getline( std::cin, s ) ) {
    std::istringstream line( s );
```

Then you can extract items using `line >> x`.